# NPE in json response

Tags: android, httpwebrequest, nullpointerexception

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String url = "http://maps.google.co.in/maps?q=restaurants&radius=5000&sll=23,72&output=json";       
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {

    InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "error....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
```

this is my simple code,

But it crashes my application. shows me NPE and uncaught exception.
can anyone help me to troubleshoot and resolve this problem.

Comment: It that right you get json as response.Doesn't seem from your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to run the below code.

```
        HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet("http://maps.google.co.in/maps?q=restaurants&radius=5000&sll=23,72&output=json");

        DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpResponse response = hc.execute(getMethod);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
        // to worry about connection release

        if (entity != null) 
        {
            InputStream inStream = entity.getContent();
            result= convertStreamToString(inStream);
            Log.i("------------------ Reulst",result);
        }
```

---

```
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
{
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   String line = null;
   try 
   {
       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
       {
           sb.append(line + "\n");
       }
   } 
   catch (IOException e) 
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } 
   finally 
   {
       try 
       {
           is.close();
       } 
       catch (IOException e) 
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   return sb.toString();
```

}

Comment: the above code which i post it works fine for me thats i m asking for error log